# Tableview from Firebase Realtime database not always updating items

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am testing my app where I have included a tableview that shows items from a Firebase Realtime database.

Every time I create a new object from the app to Firebase, the tableview updates and include the new added object.

But I have detected that sometimes it doesn't maintain the items updated.

For example, if I add a new item from inside the app, it is automically included in the tableView.

If another user creates a new item from inside his app, it is also included and updated in both apps.

But I have detected that not all items are included in the tableview and if I edit an item directly in the firebase console,the app doesn't update inmediatelly the item in the tableview.

Here is the code I am using to populate the tableview:

```
  databaseRef.child(codigo_chat).queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


            if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
            {
                let texto_mensaje = valueDictionary["mensaje"]
                let codigo_chat = valueDictionary["codigo_chat"]
                let datetime = valueDictionary["datetime"]
                let emisor = valueDictionary["emisor"]
                let receptor = valueDictionary["receptor"]

                self.mensajesSorted.insert(MisMensajes(codigo_chat: codigo_chat!, datetime: datetime!,emisor: emisor!, mensaje: texto_mensaje!, receptor: receptor! ), at: 0)

                self.chatTV.reloadData()
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're only observing the `.childAdded` event, which (as its name implies) only fires when a child is added to the location (and initially for all existing children).

If you also want to get called when a child is modified, you should also observe the `.childChanged` event. In that callback you can then update the existing UI for that child.

In the save vein there are two more events you may want to respond to:

- `.childRemoved`, which is fired when a child is removed from the database, and you'll want to remove it from the UI.
- `.childMoved`, which is fired when the child is moved to a different location in the query results, and which typically goes hand-in-hand with a `.childChanged` event. In your `.childMoved` code, you'll usually move the UI element for the child to its new location.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `reloadData` in the main queue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.chatTV.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: it doesn't solve the main issue, for example, after scrolling the tableview up and down, some items are removed or not shown.

Comment: I think you've only mentioned the issue of tableView not getting updated immediately after updating the model and calling the reload function. Why don't you post another question regarding your other issues?